# open() : Device or Resource busy

Tags: android, c, file

I am trying to read the frame buffer from an Android device using the following line of code:

```
int fd = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY | O_LARGEFILE);
```

I have been testing on a few phones, and it has always worked perfectly. Today I tried with an Android tablet, the Motorola Xoom, and I got the following error message:

```
Device or resource busy
```

In the shell, the following doesn't work (device or resource busy):

```
cat fb0
```

But the following does work:

```
/system/bin/cat fb0
```

Isn't that strange?

I am not sure why this is happening with an Android tablet but not a phone. Does anyone please know why this is happening and how to solve it please?

Comment: Where is the cat from your path?

Comment: What are the permissions on /dev/graphics/fb0 and what user are you logged in as on the console?  See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10930/why-do-we-need-a-rooted-phone-to-capture-screenshots

Comment: cat is both in /system/bin and /system/xbin. The one in /system/bin works, the one in /system/xbin gives me the "device or resource busy" error.

Comment: crw-rw-rw- root     graphics  29,   0 2011-12-01 00:47 fb0

Comment: I just tried to give it permission 777 (complete control): crwxrwxrwx root     graphics  29,   0 2011-12-01 00:47 fb0. It didn't help.

Comment: Weird - hopefully someone can shed some light on it.  You could always shell out to copy it and hack support for the Xoom but that hardly sees like a solution.

Comment: True. I don't think that would fix the open() problem.

Comment: I am getting the issue even with /system/bin/cat now. Very strange.

Comment: Did you try `lsof` to see which process has `fb0` open?

Comment: I have the same problem. lsof tells that surfaceflinger have it opened